# here maps js: bounds object structure changes

Tags: javascript, heremaps

Does anybody know the definition of Bounds object for Here maps?
I see that lately this object changed and I want to understand if that is something that has been introduced by here maps team or is that something that I misunderstand in terms of usage.

Here is my current structure usage:

```
const bounds = this.map.getViewModel().getLookAtData().bounds;
const validBounds = !!bounds.ka && !!bounds.ma && !!bounds.ca && !!bounds.ga;
```

Before the bounds object did contain params: ka, ma, ca & ga, but now it contains another structure:

```
{
  "ba": -122.40796195239258,
  "ga": -122.40595029563141,
  "ja": 37.78805124332001,
  "la": 37.78498608822109,
  "b": null,
  "a": null,
  "c": null
}
```

So my question would be is this something that I misunderstood or did the object structure just change?

Answer (score 0):

If anyone also stumbles upon this, then the answer is that HERE map team changed the object in their latest version 3.1.22.1. I reverted to that earlier one 3.1.22.0 and it contains the previous object structure.